# Python2 connexion framework - controller in directory structure

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, routes, connexion, python-routes

I am playing around with using the connexion framework to setup a REST API access for my application.

My application is is built on python2, I installed the connexion framework for python2 and played around with the yaml file via the editor (editor.swagger.io). I downloaded the Python Flask server code, converted it to be compatable with Python2 and tested for a single controller.

When the controller is placed in the same directory as the place where the server is run. Everything was fine - all routes were added and working as expected. I then proceeded to split the controller based on some business logic and wanted a tree structure for each controller.

Something like

```
myapp/api/magic1/magic1_controller.py
myapp/api/magic2/magic2_controller.py
```

and so on.
This does not work for python2. It seems to work for python3. Any ideas why?
I get the following error from logs

```
DEBUG:connexion.api:Security Definitions: {}
DEBUG:connexion.api:Validate Responses: False
DEBUG:connexion.api:Creating API blueprint: /api
DEBUG:connexion.api:Adding swagger.json: /api/swagger.json
DEBUG:connexion.api:Adding swagger-ui: /api/ui/
DEBUG:connexion.api:Adding /api/magic1/{name}...
ERROR:connexion.api:Failed to add operation for GET /api/magic1/{name}
```

In the yaml config file I add the OperationId as api.magic1.func1() and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Following the information you provided here the `operationId` should be set to `api.magic1.magic1_controller.func1` and not `api.magic1.magic1.func1()`.

You are missing to provide more details about your problem. Code snippets would help to guide you in a more detailed solution.